# Help with graph of function

Tags: functions

I need help with a question that asks this:

Let $f(x)= -1/x$ and $g(x)=e^x$ find the domain , range ,monotonicity intervals. Draw the graph of $g(f(x))$.

Everything else except the graph is pretty easy but trying to find the graph has left  me pretty confused.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should show what you have found so far.

Comment: Whah is the domain of $g(f(x))$? The range, sign, derivatives, limits to infinity and disc, points, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have

$$g(f(x))=e^{-\frac1x}=\frac1{e^\frac1x}$$

and we need to determine th egraph at least: domain, range, sign, limit at $\pm \infty$ and at discontinuity points, derivative for monotonicity intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$g(f(x)) = e^{-1/x}$$

The function is not defined at $x=0$

The right limit at $x=0$ is $0$ and the left limit is $\infty$

As $x\to \pm \infty$ your values approach $y=1$ so you have a horizontal asymptote of $y=1$

You can easily the graph given the above information and some considering the monotonicity of the exponential functions.